# Best way to re-build index using Lucene.NET in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, search, lucene.net

I am using SimpleLucene and Lucene.NET for search in my ASP.NET Webforms application. Our application is a simple Q and A site and I decided to use Lucene to do dedicated search for questions. My problem is that everytime new question gets added to the database, I need to re-build Lucene index. What is the best way to do it? My understanding is that while index is getting re-built, Lucene search will be non-functional. When site will have millions of questions re-building of index may take long time. What is the best solution?

Comment: `everytime new question gets added to the database, I need to re-build Lucene index` Why? you don't need.

Comment: If i dont refresh index, question will not come up in a search...

Comment: Not really. If you commit the indexwriter, and `reopen` the reader you can see newly updated documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating a task and adding it to the queue as per example on SimpleLucene site.